# ListActivity Items space

Tags: android, listactivity

I 'm trying to mimic the grouped tableview from iPhone in one of my ListActivities. Like sections I'd like just to give some space between two items. Does anyone know how to do this? I have tried using padding but nothing.

I have used custom adapter following the tutor: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

set `android:dividerHeight` on list view

Comment: This is good, but I want to apply it only in one particular item.

Comment: like which one? the first and second?

Comment: the last one (is like a button to send you to another activity)

Comment: use a footer with different layout (possibly similiar to your list items but with some marginTop..) for that..

you can provide headers and footers on listview with different layouts easily or in your adapters getView find out if the position is last and inflate a different layout

Comment: I've done it but I cannot set the top margin. This is my code. 
View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.button_item, null);
TextView text = (TextView) footer.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("Submit");
v.addFooterView(footer);
The last item appeared together with the rest of the list items. The marginTop is been set in the button_item.xml